# Trying to create an organized table in Python with some parsed HTML data

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Here is my code so far (and thanks to Martijn Pieters for helping me figure out the bottom portion!)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01")

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
            print(cell.text)
```

When I was inspecting the elements of the table of the website in the `url` variable, the problem is is that the values of the columns (1, 2, 3, and so forth) are in the same class called `yspscores`. My idea was to use an `if` statement to state how to deal with them, but since their class is the same as the rest of the values in the score area, it would not work.

However, I noticed also that those numbers specifically have a width = 24, whilst the scores underneath them do not. Is it even possible to reference that in the code so that Python can recognize it and separate it from the rest of the values in a neat fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `width=24` attribute to separate them.

```
for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
    if cell.get('width') == 24:
        print cell.text
```